# How to reverse engineer a website login

Tags: c#, http, post, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make a Windows 8 app that gives users access to the features of https://www.myhealth.va.gov/  .   The site requires users to log in to use it.  I can see the post request that's used in the the Chrome Developer console and the cookie that it generates but I don't know how to use this information to let users log in through my app.

Comment: Oh wow... an app that wants my logins for some highly private/sensitive stuff. Of course I belivee that the app will never use my login for anything other than accessing that site. Where do I sign up?

Comment: If a site like that was ever intended to be accessed by third party applications, surely it would have an API available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact scenario is described and solved in the networking chapter of [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104).  Roughly like so:

1. Send an httprequest to the page that contains the login form  .
2. Save the cookies returned from this page.
3. Use your knowledge of the login page's form to recreate it's post data (using your user's login/password).
4. Add the cookies to another httprequest, and transmit the post data.