# Logging into Reddit VIA C#

Tags: c#, authentication, reddit, autologin

I'm completely stumped on where to start to do this, I want to log into Reddit via script. A console application would take username and password info from the user, attempt log in and report to the user if the log in was successful or not.

I imagine I'd start off by having the program connect to the page for the secure log in form at https://ssl.reddit.com/login

I looked at the HTML in Firefox's inspector to see what it was, and it seems you can log in by inputting your in the value="" thing, password doesn't have one, but when I manually typed value="" at the end then input the password into it and attempted to log in it still went fine.

and for how to detect if the log in was successful or not, I'm stumped. I just need a push in the right direction on how I'd do this, I imagine you guize can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse engineer a website login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793382/how-to-reverse-engineer-a-website-login)

Comment: have you look at their API http://www.reddit.com/dev/api   ?

Comment: Thanks Juan, that helps! I haven't done much programming in a while and I'm kind of unskilled in the moment though, I really have no idea how to utilize this information in a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app ID and refresh token(s), I would recommend my library [Reddit.NET](https://github.com/sirkris/Reddit.NET).  It's a free and open source managed library for the Reddit API.  It's targetted to .NET Standard 2.0, which means it is compatible with .NET Core apps.

You can install it via the NuGet Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package Reddit`

Then in your program code, do something like this:

```
using Reddit;

...

var reddit = new RedditAPI("YourRedditAppID", "YourBotUserRefreshToken");

Console.WriteLine("Username: " + reddit.Account.Me.Name);

Console.WriteLine("Cake Day: " + reddit.Account.Me.Created.ToString("D"));
```

That's it!  Reddit.NET was designed to provide easy, simple access to the Reddit API with little to no boilerplate code required.

Note that Account.Me automatically caches so you can access it repeatedly without duplicating the same API call or having to store it in a local variable.

If you don't have an app ID, I strongly recommend you get one (prefs/apps on Reddit) so you can use OAuth.  Username/password auth was deprecated for the API in favor of OAuth years ago and for very good reasons.  I realize OAuth can be a bit intimidating, but it is the better solution.